# Insert an image to an extra page before a new chapter

Tags: floats

How can I insert a figure on an extra page before a chapter starts in a LaTeX file? The figure should be counted as a part of the new chapter (i.e. in the table of contents).

I tried:

```
\chapter{first chapter}

\includegraphics{myFigure}
\chapter{second chapter}
```

The problem is that "myFigure" counts as a part of the first chapter and the chapter heading appears on the page. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem as follows:

```
\chapter{first chapter}   
\chapter*{} 
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[scale=1]{myFigure}
\end{figure}
\chapter{second chapter}
```

Comment: This appears to simply remove the chapter heading, not change it to the second chapter.  It also doesn't look like it would adjust how it appears in the table of contents (or if it does, that should be considered a bug).